# JSONField() does not save properly when nested as a child of ArrayField()

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Straightforward question: setting a field as ArrayField(JSONField(...),...) using Django 1.9+ and PostgreSQL 9.4.6 does not work when saving

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = ArrayField(JSONField(blank=True, null=True), default=list([]))

# app.py
...
data = request.data #ie. [{...}, {...}] 
# variations that were tested:
# JSON.stringify([{...}, {...}, ...])
# JSON.stringify([JSON.stringify({...}), JSON.stringify({...}), ...]
# any mix of non-JSON.stringified and stringified objects being sent via AJAX

Foo(bar=data)

# error message:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "bar" is of type \
jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("bar") VALUES (ARRAY['{"name": ...
                                                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: have you tried `Foo(fooField=data)` where `data` is a dictionary rather than a string? IE `Foo(fooField=json.loads(request.data))`?

Comment: @Hamms I get this error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list'
...which begs the question, if JSON has to be 'str', then it can't possibly be jsonb[] even when saved properly (it will always be text[])

Comment: what if you attempt something like `Foo(fooField={})`?

Comment: @Hamms I'm trying to save an Array of JSON objects...not a single JSON object, so that won't make sense.

Comment: @imdaveho If `requests.data` is actually a list of json objects, `Foo(fooField=json.loads(request.data[0]))` should work. Could you iterate the list? Otherwise, JSON supports lists as well so maybe you could do `Foo(fooField=json.dumps(request.data))` to turn a python list of dictionaries or json objects into a json list in string form

Comment: @jDo you're right, if you could just post an answer mirroring mine below I'll use it as the default answer so you can get some points (I'm an SO newb, so I'll gladly give credit where credit is due)

Comment: @imdaveho You, Sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! :) ...and honestly, my comment was a shot in the dark based on a bit of experience with core python and json rather than django. I'm fine with you accepting your own answer just so the question won't re-surface as unanswered for years to come.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@jDO it seems your comment is correct. There is no need to nest JSONField in ArrayField as JSONField supports lists. Here is the updated code:

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = JSONField(default=list([]))

# app.py
...
data = request.data #ie. [{...}, {...}] 
Foo(bar=data)

# works!
```

Comment: I wonder if there are limitations/benefits in the kind of queries we can use if we use: `JSONField(default=list)` vs `ArrayField(JSONField())`

Comment: @JoseJorgeLorenzoVila: yes there are. For instance you can filter on the length of `ArrayField`, like `.filter(bar__len=1)`, but not on `JSONField`. For that reason, this is unfortunate that we cannot nest json on array, since it's not equivalent to a simple json field. (But anyway it's probably the sign that a better design is needed).